# Why does EGit's Remote Tracking folder only contain a branch on import?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

So I'm kinda new to both EGit and Git in general, although I have managed to set up a remote repository and successfully pushed changes to it.

When i was playing around with EGit i found that if you import a project from Git, you will get a branch in you "Remote Tracking" folder in the Git Repositories view. This however is not the case when you create a new project and then connect it to a remote repository.

This is my two repositories where "New Project" is  a Java project created in eclipse and then connected to a remote repository, and "testproject" is a project i imported from Git (Bitbucket).

[Git Repository view](http://tinypic.com/r/15iur9/8)

Is this just a setting I've missed when creating my "New Project", or is this how it is supposed to be?

Comment: For "New Project", can you describe step by step what you are doing to "connect it to a remote repository"?

Comment: I've tried two ways.  

 1. First i clone a repository (with URI from Bitbucket) in the "Git Repositories" view and then right-click the project and then "Share Project" and then I just select the newly created repository.  

2. I create the project, right-click Team->"Share Project". I then open the "Git Repositories" view and find my local repository, right-click "Remotes" and select "Configure push" with Remote name=origin, and then paste URI from Bitbucket repo.  

I hope this was clear enough, if not ill try to improve it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to the problem. It seems as though when you configure your local Git repository and select the option "Use or create repository in parent folder of project" you will not get a branch file in the "Remote-Tracking" folder.

Something which i don't know if it matters is the way i did my first commit and push, so i'll add it here as well in case i actually does matter:

Right click the created project -> commit.
Open "Git Repositories" view -> right click your local branch -> Push Branch...